# Parallel processing of pairs of items from the list in Java8

Tags: java, list, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

In `Java8`, having a `List<Item> list` I process it sequentially as below:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list.size() - 1; i1++) {
    Item item1 = list.get(i1);
    for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < list.size(); i2++) {
        Item item2 = list.get(i2);
        doSomething(item1, item2);
    }
}
```

So I process all ordered pairs of items from the list (index of `item1` < index of `item2`). Now, I would like to run `doSomething(item1, item2)` function in parallel for each ordered pair. What would be the best strategy to achieve that? Interested in the fastest possible code. `Java8` streams are welcome.

`doSomething` for instance does: `map.put(item1.key + " " + item2.key, item1.val + item2.val);`.

The number of ordered pairs is `n * (n - 1) / 2` where `n` is the size of the list. I also consider to split the amount of job evenly to reach the load-balance (at the moment assume each pair's execution time is the same). So it is not required to call `doSomething(item1, item2)` function in parallel for each ordered pair, but possibly for a set of prepared pairs.

Comment: I rolled back the edit#4 which significantly changed the question meaning making existing answers inappropriate. If you have different question, please ask it instead of editing the old one.

Answer (score 5):

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size()).parallel()
   .forEach(i1 -> 
       IntStream.range(i1 + 1, list.size()).parallel()
           .forEach(i2 -> doSomething(list.get(i1), list.get(i2))));
```

This doesn't have to be nearly as complicated as any of the other answers.

Comment: @BrandonMcHomery, parallel stream does not create a separate thread for each pair. It works smarter.

Comment: No, you should not, parallel streams will divide the work intelligently into a correctly sized thread pool.  You don't need to worry about that for streams.

Comment: @LouisWasserman can you explain your last comment a bit further? according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) my understanding is that `.parallel()` uses the [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)

Comment: @alfasin, sure, so what?  It uses the common pool, which Java intelligently sizes.

Comment: I wasn't criticising... I thought that you meant that it creates the pool, and wanted to learn if there is such a feature for ForkJoinPool (creating more instances of it)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to control the number of running threads (i.e. the list is relatively small) you can run them in parallel like this:

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list.size() - 1; i1++) {
    Item item1 = list.get(i1);
    for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < list.size(); i2++) {
        Item item2 = list.get(i2);
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSomething(item1, item2);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

If the list is long the code above will spin one thread for each pair of items which could effect performance really badly. In such a case I would use a [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) and create a `newFixedThreadPool` to limit the number of threads that could be span up simultaneously:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list.size() - 1; i1++) {
    Item item1 = list.get(i1);
    for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < list.size(); i2++) {
        Item item2 = list.get(i2);

        executor.execute(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSomething(item1, item2);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a new thread for every pair of items is likely to have terrible performance.

Comment: @LouisWasserman depends on the size of the list. If it's only a few items that shouldn't be too bad. That said, if the list is long, it would be a good idea to use a fixed-size threadpool. I'll add it to the answer - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've added the special feature to my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library (since version 0.3.6) just to solve this issue: [`EntryStream.ofPairs`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#ofPairs-java.util.List-) method:

```
EntryStream.ofPairs(list).parallel()
    .forKeyValue((item1, item2) -> doSomething(item1, item2));
```

If you don't mind using third-party library, you may try this. Internally it's different from the accepted solution. It splits the set of `n*(n-1)/2` possible pairs as evenly as possible, so parallelism could be more effective in this case.